# 'for' loop repeating beginning WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to get a for loop to iterate over a box of row elements but my XPATH locator keeps returning the beginning element over and over. If I try use a class name locator I get a nosuchElement exception. How do I get it to get the next element in the row elements

Your help would be greatly appreciated

website: ttps://www.betway.co.ke/Event/LiveSport

the markup is as follows:

```html
markup is as follows:



<div class="row eventRow" id="01e346b7-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" data-event-id="01e346b7-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" data-markettitle="Match Result (1X2)" data-eventtitle="AL Wakrah v Sadd" data-sporttitle="Soccer" data-eventdate="2022-01-31 16:30"
  data-value="01e346b7-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" data-market="12e0c327-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" data-markettype="de677d0c-e70f-e811-80d9-00155d4cf18a" data-markettypecategory="00000000-0000-0000-da7a-000000580003">
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-4 eventDetails padding--none" id="eventDetails_0">
    <div class="inplayStatusDetails col-xs-10 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="/sport/soccer/qat/stars_league/al_wakrah-v-sadd/0?inplay=true&amp;datefilter=202201311630">
        <label data-translate-type="event" data-translate-set="Soccer" data-translate-market="Match Result (1X2)" data-translate-key="AL Wakrah v Sadd" class="ellips theOtherFont" style="width:95%"><b>AL Wakrah v Sadd</b></label>
        <label class="ellips theOtherFont liveEllips label__league_title">
                                                31
                                                <label data-translate-set="DatePicker" data-translate-key="">
                                                    Jan
                                                </label> 16:30 QAT Stars League
        </label>
      </a>
      <br>
      <label class="pull-left label__live_status" style="padding-right:5px" data-translate-set="SportContent" data-translate-key="" data-event-status="1st half">1st half</label>
      <label class="pull-left label__live_status" data-event-time=""> | 40:57 min </label>
      <label class=" pull-left label__live_status" data-event-score="0 - 0"> | 0 - 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 event-icons no-sidePaddings">
      <div data-translate-set="SportContent" data-translate-key="" data-translate-type="title" title="Cashout is available for certains market on this event." class="co-img co-img-white pull-right mm-co toolTipIcon" onclick="events.showTip()" data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="auto left"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 outcomes lipRowTopMargin " data-elementtype="outcomeRow">



    <div class="outcomeBtnLong outcomebuttonDiv">
      <div id="2148688e-e27f-ec11-80ef-00155d10891a" style="" class="btn btn-group btn-bettingmatch inplay" data-sortindex="0" data-lip-sbv="None" onclick="gax.SetBetPOI('Sport Page', this.id);
            SendToBetslip
            (
                this.id,
                'AL Wakrah',
                '9.2500',
                'Soccer',
                'Match Result (1X2)',
                'None',
                'AL Wakrah v Sadd',
                '1/31/2022 4:30:00 PM',
                '01e346b7-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                'True',
                 true,
                 false,
                 'Stars League'
              ); ">

        <div data-translate-type="outcome" data-translate-set="Soccer" data-translate-market="Match Result (1X2)" data-translate-key="AL Wakrah" class="outcome-title text-left  ">AL Wakrah</div>


        <div class="outcome-pricedecimal" data-lip-value="2148688e-e27f-ec11-80ef-00155d10891a" data-lip-pricedecimal="50.00" style="">50.00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Python code is as follows:

```js
from selenium.common.exceptions
import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver
import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
import Options
from selenium
import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service
import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by
import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support
import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select
import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait
import WebDriverWait
import time

options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')# headless = true

web = 'https://www.betway.co.ke/Event/LiveSport'
path = '/Users/mac/bin/chromedriver'#path to chromedriver
s = Service(path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s, options = options)
driver.get(web)


teams = []
x12 = []
btts = []
odds_events = []




dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filtermarket-button"]'))).click()
dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
  '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/'
  'div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/'
  'div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]')))
dropdown.click()
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   time.sleep(10)
box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'bettingtabs').find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tab-content')
#xpath_str = "//div[@class='row' or @class='eventRow']"
time.sleep(5)
rows = box.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@data-markettitle, "Match Result (1X2)")]')

time.sleep(5)
for row in rows:
odds = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-xs-12')
odds_events.append(odds.text)
print(odds_events)


input('press ENTER to exit browser')
driver.quit()
```

result:

```js
['Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n14.50', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n14.50', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n14.50', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n14.50', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00', 'Casa Pia Lisbon\n1.22\nDraw\n4.40\nPenafiel\n15.00']
press ENTER to exit browser
```

Comment: .// For xpathing from element.

Comment: if I use current node for xpath it returns a NosuchElement exception

Comment: Can you share ALL your code? Seems like you are not working on the home page, right?

Comment: @Prophet I have added everything above

Comment: The login steps are missing..

Comment: I am only in need of the odds values, I won't need to login atm

Comment: I can't see element matching `//*[@id="filtermarket-button"]` on the landing page

Comment: its the dropdown at the top area of the page, marked as Bet type. ID attr. has been changed to 'filtermarket-list'

Comment: @Prophet thanks, I got it to work. you were right earlier the row element was not right

Comment: I'm happy I could help you